# Adding Attributes in Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a bunch of attributes that pertain to a specific functionality. They are quite a pain to write so I decided that it would be best to write it as a directive.

The problem is there doesn't seem to be a simple way to add attributes in a directive. For example, in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927469/how-to-add-validation-attributes-in-an-angularjs-directive), to add the directive compile has to still be called, and it's using the attr method of jqlite.

And that is the problem: directives as a usable component, how would I add attributes painlessly?

For example, if I want to add an ng-class, it's not going to be easy because there would have to be string manipulation `('{myClass:foo}' + '{directiveClass:bar}', to {myClass:foo, directiveClass:bar})`;

Or is it a bad idea to add attributes to directives? The problem is I can't add the attributes in a template because it must be attributes to the actual element (because it might break styles, etc.))

Comment: I think a lot of people bumped into that problem ie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116470/add-ng-click-dynamically-in-directive-link-function/22117648 and as you can see at the end they've cheated :) be creative :) using compile it's very cpu consuming (try to see how many loops inside the compile function just a lot !) with a lot of headache ^^

Comment: "I can't add the attributes in a template because it must be attributes to the actual element"… Simply use `replace : true` ?

Comment: @Blackhole Holy F why is this not in the docs!? :O

Comment: Actually, it's [here in the doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-) ;) .