# AngularJS: how to compile form in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a custom directive that set 'required' and 'disabled' attributes to the element (form input). The directive gets this data from the scope object. But clearing of required field doesn't set my form to invalide state. I think it's about form compilation after changing the attribute. I tried to do that but got an infinite loop :(
How to compile my form correctly?

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cioDtT1CN16VPfEdhzUB?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `ng-disabled` and `ng-required`, instead of adding the attributes in a directive.

```
<div>
  <label for="username">username2</label>
  <input ng-model="data.account.username2" 
  ng-disabled="paintData['data.account.username2'] == 'RO'" 
  ng-required="paintData['data.account.username2'] == 'R'" />
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could define a directive template that uses `ng-disabled` and `ng-required`, and replace the original element with it:

```
.directive('metaValidate', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      model: '=',
      paint: '='
    },
    template: '<input ng-model="model" ng-disabled="readonly" ng-required="required"/>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.required = scope.paint[element.attr('model')] === 'R';
      scope.readonly = scope.paint[element.attr('model')] === 'RO';
    }
  };
});
```

Then, use it like this:

```
<input model="data.account.username2" meta-validate paint="paintData"/>
```

I prefer the first approach, because it can respond to changes to `paintData`.  But, you have to repeat the property name several times.

If you want to try this code, [here is an update of your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pIcXjzxaR46sFo3WVZHJ?p=preview).

Comment: Yes, the repeating of name - it's exactly that I'm trying to avoid. If I have a form with couple of fields, of course I'd use ng-disabled. But unfortunately my form has more than 200 elements and in this case using of ng-required seems little painful :)

Comment: Btw, I've figured out how to force the first approach to be responsive to changes to paintData. Here is an update: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/cy2reJwZiLX9LBhJUbfO?p=preview). Thank you very much, guys!

Comment: nice, @vicont.  i like it.

Comment: Here is improved version of [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PU7ssC9HhwdSBaW2mNwp?p=info). It doesn't require to explicitly set the "paint" attribute for every element, instead of it we watch the object from parent scope (yes, it's a hardcoded dependency, but it's ok for this certain case). May be it would be useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Recompiling the element could work, but in order to avoid the infinite loop you need to first remove the `meta-validate` attribute (which would cause yet more compiling etc):

```
/* At the end of the directive's link function */
attrs.$set('metaValidate', undefined);
$compile(element)(scope);
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zeSq9yx1o9Ug6WmxI2CR?p=preview)**.