# Directive that adds validation directive erasing data from textbox on $invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927469/how-to-add-validation-attributes-in-an-angularjs-directive)*
got me the closest to implementing this correctly but as soon as my field sets the `$invalid` key on the form (at least I think that's what it is) it erases the text inside my text box

[here's my plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/mqAVhh3ipoF49KuCIMjW?p=preview)

Comment: try compiling whole form `$compile(element.form)(scope)` instead of `$compile(element[0].form)(scope)`

Comment: thanks... but it doesnt work. try it out in my plnker link at "here's my plnk"

Comment: I have added answer. Check if it is useful to you or not?

Answer (score 0):

In order to work your directive, you need to add `priority:1000` so that will get executes the code before any directive gets executed & other thing before compiling the DOM you need to remove directive attribute `meta-validate` so that it will not execute while compiling. If you don't do that then you will get `Maximum Call stack exceeds.` error.

**Directive**

```
 myApp.directive('metaValidate', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      priority: 1000, //this setting is important to make sure it executes before other directives
      compile: function compile(element, attrs) {
        return {
          pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { if(!element.attr('ng-maxlength')){
              element.attr('ng-maxlength', '2');
              element.removeAttr("meta-validate");
            } },
          post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  
            $compile(element)(scope);
          }
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/78ZB6NqapOR0nY4tu5ZQ?p=preview)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.