# pass callback to directive - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to add an animation to an element via a directive. When the animation is done I want it to call the passed callback function. I try to do achieve it this way ([SO - How to add validation attributes in an angularjs directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927469/how-to-add-validation-attributes-in-an-angularjs-directive))

The 'addAnimation' directive:

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .directive('addAnimation', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        onFinish:"&"
      },
      replace: false,
      terminal: true,
      priority: 1000,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function() {           
          $('.selector').animate({ ... }), function() {
            if(attrs.cb) {
              attrs.cb.onFinish();
            }
          });             
        })

        element.removeAttr("addAnimation"); //remove the attribute to avoid indefinite loop

        $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    };
  });
```

The directive 'aDirective' the animation should be added to:

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .directive('aDirective', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.test = function() {
          console.log('this should be logged');
        }
      }
    };
  });


<div>
  <div add-animation cb="{onFinish: 'test'}"></div>
</div>
```

When I click it, the animation starts, but then I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: attrs.cb.onFinish is not a function
```

Logging `attrs.cb` seems like its not resolving the function:

```
{onFinish: 'test'}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined `onFinish` on the directive's scope, you should use it like on scope, It needs to be used in the element as `on-finish`,so instead of:

```
attrs.cb.onFinish()
```

do

```
scope.onFinish()
```

Also, if you define it like this:

```
scope: {
    onFinish:"&"
},
```

you should pass it into the directive this way:

```
<div add-animation on-finish="test()"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, it works. Just the onFinish inside the div need to be on-finish. I cant edit it.